# Integral with a delta dirac in a finite interval

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

The dirac delta can be defined in such a way that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(z)\,dz = 1
$$

and, for a suitable $f$, it holds that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)\,\delta(z)\,dz = f(0).
$$

What can be said about the integral (take $a>0$)

$$
\int_0^{a}f(z)\,\delta(z)\,dz\quad?
$$

Is still true that $\int_0^{a}f(z)\,\delta(z)\,dz=f(0)$ ? I am pretty sure that, for all $\varepsilon>0$, then

$$
\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}f(z)\,\delta(z)\,dz=f(0),
$$

but I am in trouble when the interval of integration has the zero at its boundary.

Comment: This has been asked several times before. The most coherent definition is that, for every $a>0$, $$\int_0^af(z)\delta(z)dz=\int_{-a}^0f(z)\delta(z)dz=\frac12f(0)$$

Comment: @Did, can you prove your statement is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 0 on the boundary it is a priori not defined. It corresponds to integrating $\delta$ against the function $f 1_{x>0}$ (or possibly $f 1_{x\geq 0}$) which is not continuous at $0$ where the support of $\delta$ lies. Note that the other case $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ presents no problem since $\delta$ has support in 0.

Comment: when extending the distributions outside $C^\infty_c$, I think it is important to say that the support of $\delta$ is a neighborhood of $0$

Comment: It could be $\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{x>0} + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{x \geq 0}$ as well!

Comment: It depends on what the intended purpose is. You may e.g. want to say that when $\phi$ has compact support and integral 1 then $t\phi(tx)$ converges weakly (as $t\rightarrow \infty$)  to a Dirac delta. But when $\phi$ is not symmetric you will get into trouble when integrating on $R_+$

Comment: (+1) for the clear, concise, and correct answer.